# I cant uncheck the checkBox by using this code

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I saved the checked status of the checkbox in isolated storage but whenever i unchecked the checkbox and then start the app again it remains checked however i saved its status on backkeypress

this is from Constructor

```
if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("mySavedList"))
            {
                lstshopNew = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["mySavedList"] as List<Shopping>;

                if (lstshopNew.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var item in lstshopNew)
                    {
                        var t = lstShop.Where(s => s.list.Equals(item.list)).FirstOrDefault();

                        if (t != null)
                        {
                            t.IsCompleted = true;
                        }
                    } 
        private void checkboxSL_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        { 
            //isChkboxChecked = true;
            //(sender as CheckBox).IsChecked = isChkboxChecked;
            //IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["isChecked"] = (sender as CheckBox).IsChecked;

            var chk = (sender as CheckBox).DataContext as Shopping;

            if (chk == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            chk.IsCompleted = true;

            var lstItem = lstShop.Where(x => x.list.Equals(chk.list)).FirstOrDefault();

            if (lstItem != null)
            {
                lstshopNew.Remove(chk);
            }

            lstshopNew.Add(chk);

        }

        private void checkboxSL_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //(sender as CheckBox).IsChecked = false;
            //IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["isChecked"] = (sender as CheckBox).IsChecked;

            var chk = (sender as CheckBox).DataContext as Shopping;


            if (chk == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            chk.IsCompleted = false;

            var lstItem = lstShop.Where(x => x.list.Equals(chk.list)).FirstOrDefault();

            if (lstItem != null)
            {
                lstshopNew.Remove(chk);
            }
            lstshopNew.Remove(chk);

        }

        protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnBackKeyPress(e);

            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["mySavedList"] = lstshopNew;
        }
```

### XAML code

```
 <ListBox x:Name="listBox2" SelectionMode="Multiple" Grid.Row="1" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="White"  >
                    <CheckBox x:Name="checkboxSL" IsChecked="{Binding IsCompleted, Mode=TwoWay}" Checked="checkboxSL_Checked" Unchecked="checkboxSL_Unchecked" BorderBrush="Black" Foreground="Black" Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxStyle1}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding list}" FontSize="30" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Foreground="Black" Margin="0,15,0,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are putting `Shopping` into your isolated storage. That is an instance of a C# class with a unique memory address. You then re-run the application and check if that saved Shopping object is identical to the Shopping objects you just created. It is not, since those new objects are new instances with new memory addresses.

What you want to do is put a unique Id (like a number or unique keyword) into the Shopping class. Then compare that ID (not the whole object) to determine if the object in storage is the same as the one on the GUI.

Comment: I compared it by using the breakpoints both are same and once it is saved in storage i can not remove it

Comment: The value of each property in both objects are the same, but they are two different copies of the same object, therefore they are not the same to the code. If there is a unique I'd in Shipping you could compare that instead.

Comment: Can u give me an example

Answer (score 0):

I Made these changes to the event worked for me
  private void checkboxSL_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var chk = (sender as CheckBox).DataContext as Shopping;

```
        if (chk == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        chk.IsCompleted = true;

        var lstItem = lstShop.Where(x => x.list.Equals(chk.list)).FirstOrDefault();

        //if (lstItem != null)
        //{
        //    lstshopNew.Remove(lstItem);
        //}            

        if (lstshopNew.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in lstshopNew.ToList())
            {
                if (item.list.Equals(lstItem.list))
                {
                    tItem = item.list;
                }
            }

            if (!lstItem.list.Equals(tItem))
            {
                lstshopNew.Add(chk);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lstshopNew.Add(chk);
        }
    }

    private void checkboxSL_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var chk = (sender as CheckBox).DataContext as Shopping;

        if (chk == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        chk.IsCompleted = false;

        var lstItem = lstShop.Where(x => x.list.Equals(chk.list)).FirstOrDefault();

        if (lstItem != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in lstshopNew.ToList())
            {
                if (item.list.Equals(lstItem.list))
                {
                    lstshopNew.Remove(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```